# Select dropdown component that supports optgroup in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create an Angular 2 component that is responsible for rendering a `select` form control and I'm having some trouble trying to make it support `optgroup`.

When rendering, I need to be able to switch between an `optgroup` and an `option` element depending on whether the item has children or not. I'm attempting to use a `template` tag in order to iterate these items, but it looks like this isn't supported inside a `select`. I also tried adding `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same element but that isn't supported either.

*How do I create a `select` with `optgroup` in Angular 2?*

---

<kbd>[Plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jUOCyXmYHfbMu3zoDSkM?p=preview)</kbd>

*form-select.component.js*

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgStyle } from '@angular/common';

export class FormSelectOption {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    children: FormSelectOption[];

    constructor(id: string, text: string, children: FormSelectOption[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.children = children;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'form-select',
    template: `
    <select>
        <!-- WORKING -->
        <option *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="select(item.id)">{{item.text}}</option>

        <!-- NOT WORKING -->
        <!--<template *ngFor="let item of items">
            <optgroup *ngIf="item.children" label="{{item.text}}">
                <option *ngFor="let child of item.children" (click)="select(child.id)">{{child.text}}</option>
            </optgroup>
            <option *ngIf="!item.children" (click)="select(item.id)">{{item.text}}</option>
        </template>-->
    </select>
  `
})
export class FormSelectComponent {
    @Input()
    items: FormSelectOption[];

    @Input()
    selectedValue: string[];

    @Output()
    valueChange: EventEmitter<any>;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.valueChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
    }

    select(id) {
        this.valueChange.emit(id);
    }
}
```

*app.ts*

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {FormSelectComponent, FormSelectOption} from './form-select.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <form-select [items]="things" [selectedValue]="selectedThing"></form-select>
    `,
    directives: [FormSelectComponent],
})

export class App {
    selectedThing = '1';
    things = [
        new FormSelectOption('1', 'Fruit', [
            new FormSelectOption('2', 'Bananas'),
            new FormSelectOption('3', 'Apples'),
            new FormSelectOption('4', 'Oranges')
        ]),
        new FormSelectOption('5', 'Countries', [
            new FormSelectOption('6', 'England'),
            new FormSelectOption('7', 'New Zealand')
        ]),
        new FormSelectOption('8', 'Shapes', [
            new FormSelectOption('9', 'Square')
        ]),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
   <optgroup *ngIf="item.children" label="{{item.text}}">
     <option *ngFor="let child of item.children" (click)="select(child.id)">
       {{child.text}}
     </option>
   </optgroup>
   <option *ngIf="!item.children" (click)="select(item.id)">{{item.text}}</option>
</ng-template>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xYvGPAhFFpTCPcotqm9F?p=preview)**

**Syntax ngFor:**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
<li template="ngFor let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index"><li>...</li></ng-template>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html#!#syntax

Comment: urghh... well that's annoying. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @yurzui I got struck in same scenario.....ur plunker is not working. can you update it

Comment: @PsycheGenie Updated https://plnkr.co/edit/xYvGPAhFFpTCPcotqm9F?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJs then following code snippet may be helpful for you:

HTML Sample Code

```
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select ng-model="selectedItem" class="form-control">
                        <optgroup label="{{currentGroup}}" ng-repeat="currentGroup in groupList">
                            <option ng-value="item.key" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'name' | filter: {group: currentGroup}">
                                {{item.name}}
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

JavaScript Sample Code

```
$scope.items = [{
    key: '1',
    name: "Apple",
    group: 'Fruit'
  }, {
    key: '2',
    name: "Banana",
    group: 'Fruit'
  }, {
    key: '3',
    name: "Orange",
    group: 'Fruit'
  }, {
    key: '4',
    name: "Tomato",
    group: 'Vegetable',
  }, {
    key: '5',
    name: "Potato",
    group: 'Vegetable'
  }];

  $scope.groupList = $scope.items.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    if (previous.indexOf(current.group) === -1) {
      previous.push(current.group);
    }

    return previous;
  }, []);
```

Thanks